# How to get the image information based on the image id which I already have with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I click on a certain image, I send the user to :

```
<a href='/image/{{ $image->id }}'>
```

The route that handles this is:

```
Route::get('/image/{id}', 'PagesController@specificImage')->name('specificImage');
```

This function should get the information of the image with that id and pass it to a view. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to get the information of the image with id of `$imageId`.

```
public function specificImage($id) {
    $imageId = $id;
}
```

Comment: do you have any table or model to store image info??

Comment: Yes, I have a table that contains everything, I just need to somehow only access 1 row that has the id $imageId

Comment: please add your image model in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model name for `image` table is `Image` -

```
$image = Image::find($imageId);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't even need to look it up if you use typehinting:

```
public function specificImage(Image $image){
    // $image will now contain the image you're looking for
}
```